# Azure Active Directory failing to get authentication token

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I am using Azure Active Directory and trying to get logged in user details. I am trying the code from [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web/blob/master/WebAppGraphAPI/Controllers/UserProfileController.cs). I am blocked at this point where it is unable to get user authorization token. Any suggestions or pointers?

Error message:

AuthorizationRequired
at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenSilentHandler.SendTokenRequestAsync() at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AcquireTokenHandlerBase.d__0.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.d__10.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext.d__5c.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)

Comment: I'm guessing [this line](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web/blob/master/WebAppGraphAPI/Utils/AuthenticationHelper.cs#L24) is throwing that exception. Seems like the token was not acquired properly in `Startup.Auth.cs`?

Comment: i think that may be the issue?

Comment: If you restarted the app, it's possible your login cookie is still valid, but the app has lost the token that was in memory. You could try removing the cookie. Otherwise you should attach a breakpoint to the `AuthorizationCodeReceived` callback on [this line](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web/blob/master/WebAppGraphAPI/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs#L64).